# Conditionally concatenate string values of a tuple in a list in python based on the elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, concatenation

Here is the list which includes tags to the word type

```
t = [('The','OTHER'),('name','OTHER'),('is','OTHER'),('Wall','ORGANIZATION'),('Mart','ORGANIZATION'),('and','OTHER'),('Thomas','ORGANIZATION'),('Cook','ORGANIZATION')]
```

The expectation is to conditionally check if the subsequent tuple is tagged as organization if so concatenate them with a space and continue with the same over the entire list.

**Expected output:**

```
Wall Mart, Thomas Cook

for x in t:
    if(x[1] == 'ORGANIZATION'):
         org_list = org_list + ' | ' + x[0]
```

I was just able to extract the names but not really getting a way where I could concatenate the words tagged as organization.

Refereed to other Question asked: [Link][Concatenate elements of a tuple in a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736917/concatenate-elements-of-a-tuple-in-a-list-in-python[Link])

**Expected output:** Wall Mart, Thomas Cook

Comment: `tenant_list = [item[0] for item in t if item[1] == 'ORGANIZATION']` will give you a list of the items you want

Comment: what should be the expected output for such input `[('Wall','ORGANIZATION'), ('and','OTHER'), ('Mart','ORGANIZATION'), ('Cook','ORGANIZATION')]` ?

Comment: I want to concatenate the word in the subsequent tag as mentioned in the description what you have mentioned is just extracting the Words having organizations in them.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Lol. Expected output should be: Wall, Mart Cook

Comment: Will there always be an `OTHER` between two subsequent `ORGANIZATION`?

Comment: @yatu Yes, there will be an OTHER between two subsequent ORGANIZATION.

Comment: Okay then my approach should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there will always be an `'OTHER'` between two subsequent `'ORGANIZATION'`, one approach is using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group subsequent tuples by their second element, and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html) their first items if the grouping `key` is `'ORGANIZATION'`:

```
t = [('The','OTHER'),('name','OTHER'),('is','OTHER'),('Wall','ORGANIZATION'),
     ('Mart','ORGANIZATION'),('and','OTHER'),('Thomas','ORGANIZATION'),
     ('Cook','ORGANIZATION')]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter as g

[' '.join(i[0] for i in [*v]) for k,v in groupby(t, key=g(1)) if k=='ORGANIZATION']
# ['Wall Mart', 'Thomas Cook']
```

---

If you prefer a for loop solution without any imports, you can do: -- This will work only for two subsequent tags:

```
f = False
out = []
for i in t:
    if i[1] == 'ORGANIZATION':
        if not f:
            out.append(i[0])
            f = True
        else:
            out[-1] += f' {i[0]}'
            f = False

print(out)
# ['Wall Mart', 'Thomas Cook']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
t = [('The','OTHER'),('name','OTHER'),('is','OTHER'),('Wall','ORGANIZATION'),('Mart','ORGANIZATION'),('and','OTHER'),('Thomas','ORGANIZATION'),('Cook','ORGANIZATION')]

result = [[]]
for i, j in t:
    if j == 'ORGANIZATION':
        result[-1].append(i)
    elif result[-1]:
        result.append([])       

result = [' '.join(i) for i in result if i]
# ['Wall Mart', 'Thomas Cook']
```